# Select and delete a created child element javascript

Tags: javascript

Newbie to JS here. Creating a notetaking app where i can create, add and delte notes using classes and constructor.
However I'm having trouble running the delete function.
It only deletes the recently created note. Here's the code

```js
class stickyNotes {
  constructor(id, content) {
    this.id
    this.content
    this.createNotes()
    this.addNotes()
  }

  createNotes(id, content) {
    newNote = document.createElement("textarea")
    newNote.classList.add('new_note')
    newNote.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    newNote.value = content
    // newNote.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //     // console.log(id)
    // })

    newNote.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const doDelete = confirm(
        "Are you sure you wish to delete this sticky note?"
      );

      if (doDelete) {
        this.deleteNotes(id, newNote);
      }
    });
    return newNote
  }

  addNotes() {
    noteObject = {
      id: "",
      content: ""
    }
    notesArr.push(noteObject)
    noteObject.id = notesArr.indexOf(noteObject)

    let noteEL = this.createNotes(noteObject.id, noteObject.content)
    noteBank.append(noteEL)
  }

  deleteNotes(id, newNote) {
    // let notes = notesArr.filter((note) => note.id == id);

    console.log(notes);
    noteBank.removeChild(notes)
  }
}
```

Trying to isolate it from an array didn't work

Is there a way to specifically select an element created with objects?

Comment: this is because your have declared `newNote` as a global variable

Comment: Yeah always use let/const. (if you say "use strict" on top of the file it would have caught it for you) @MisterJojo is correct.

Comment: JavaScript naming conventions for Classes: 

Start class names with a capital letter, use PascalCase for names.